# Why is a bandwidth discrepancy occurring despite consistent Q factors in the given Graph?

Tags: impedance, s-parameters, vna, common-mode-choke

I was trying to do curve fitting the common-mode choke in CST Studio according to the selected S4P file from TDK ([ACT1210G-800-2P-TL05](https://product.tdk.com/en/search/emc/emc/cmf_cmc/info?part_no=ACT1210G-800-2P-TL10)).

[image: S4p file connected in common mode topology]

However, the common-mode impedance measured from the file does not align with the schematic (self made).

[image: Schematic of common mode choke]

I'm unable to optimize it; both graphs are not aligning. What am I missing?
[image: Common mode impedance vs frequency]

I attempted to change all the parameters and do curve fitting , but even though the Q factor remains the same, the bandwidth is different. Is there something wrong with my schematic? Is my common-mode connection in the S4P file correct?)

Comment: You are measuring the impedance with output grounded. The data sheet does not mention how manufacturer measured the parameters, but I bet they are measured differently.

Comment: What's being optimized; does your program adjust component values automatically, is that what is being optimized? So you are attempting to curve-fit the provided data with a circuit? (Implied: you are getting poor fitness because your schematic doesn't match the data, or there is a problem with optimizer convergence.)

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which line in the graph is from the TDK *S*-parameter file and which is from your schematic. Please specify.

But one thing is clear: the orange line shows *much* lower inductance than the purple line. You can see that below the resonance, e.g. at 100MHz, the impedances are about a factor 10 different! So the first thing you must do is change `Lcore` in the schematic (by about a factor 10) to get the low-frequency value matched.

Then you must adjust the capacitors `Cp p` to get the resonance frequency back to the correct position, and then the resistors `Rcore` to get the bandwidth correct. All the time making sure that the leakage inductance and the associated components (on the left of the schematic) play no role.
After that you will have the common-mode impedance correct.

You can then also try to model the differential-mode impedance (change the connection in the testbench, adjust `Lleak n`, `Cpar p`, and `Rpara`).